# TextInputLayout "setError(null)" before "setErrorEnabled(false)" necessary?

Tags: java, android, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, android-textinputlayout

Is it necessary to call `setError(null)` before `setErrorEnable(false)`? Why? I don't see the difference but I see many people do that.

Comment: Just because when there is no requirement to show error for field then we set setErrorEnable(false) and to clear existing error into that field we use setError(null).

Comment: @Nice umang But if I want to remove the error I just use `setErrorEnable(false)` is good enough for me (at least from what I see on the screen), at this point calling `setError(null)` before that becomes unnecessary I think, because I don't see the difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to call both of them. When you set an error for a ***TextInputLayout*** at the first time, it's height increase a little under it's ***EditText*** field for showing that error.

If you use `setError(null)` just the error text will delete, but if you use `setErrorEnable(false)` both error text and extra space will delete(note that if you have set a helper for ***TextInputLayout***, the error simply replace with the helper text and doesn't add an extra space so you don't see any difference between this two methods).